# JCR Query on mixinproperties

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

I am having difficulties querying a jcr node in jackrabbit, containing certain property.

I've added a custom node to add mixin properties to it.

```
<custom = 'http://example.com/mydomain'>
[custom:extensible] mixin
- * (undefined) multiple 
- * (undefined)
```

Then I add a nt:file nodes in the following way and to those nt:file I add my custom:extensible

```
documents = session.getRootNode().getNode(MainJCRConstants.MAIN_NODE);
documentNode = documents.addNode(fileName, NodeType.NT_FILE);
Node resNode = documentNode.addNode(JcrConstants.JCR_CONTENT, NodeType.NT_RESOURCE);
Binary binary = session.getValueFactory().createBinary(ins);
resNode.setProperty(JcrConstants.JCR_DATA, binary);
resNode.addMixin("custom:extensible");
resNode.setProperty("sourceSystem", "internal");
```

And now I want to query all [nt:file] nodes, containing property "sourceSystem" which value is equal to "internal".

After looking at the documentation I fugred I have to use something similar to:

```
SELECT parent.* FROM [nt:file] AS parent 
INNER JOIN [custom:extensible] AS child ON ISCHILDNODE(child,parent) 
WHERE CONTAINS(parent.*, 'internal') OR CONTAINS(child.*,'internal')
```

But this throws an exception http://pastebin.com/ZdxZPf2C

Also every other query I've tried either throws an exception or returns an empty result set.

**Solution:**

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:resource] as res INNER JOIN [custom:extensible] AS ext ON ISSAMENODE(res,ext) WHERE CONTAINS(res.sourceSystem,'internal') OR CONTAINS(ext.sourceSystem,'internal')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query a node both by primary type and mixin, and it does require using a JOIN. However, the join criteria should be a `ISSAMENODE` criteria:

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:file] AS file
   INNER JOIN [custom:extensible] AS ext ON ISSAMENODE(file,ext)
WHERE CONTAINS(file.*,'internal') OR CONTAINS(ext.*,'internal')
```

This query joins all `nt:file` nodes with all `custom:extensible` nodes, ensuring that the only pairing in the results occur when the `nt:file` node and `custom:extensible` nodes are the same node.

Also note that the `SELECT *` may mean your results contain duplicate columns, so you may consider explicitly selecting the columns your are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This however didn't work it returns an empty result set. I fugured... shouldn't I use [nt:resource] to query those for this property, because from the implementation it seems to me I am adding another node to [nt:file] which is [nt:resource] and there I set the properties?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought the 'CONTAINS' were for the 'nt:file' properties. Yes, if you want to query the content of the file, you'd also need to join with the 'nt:resource' child node.

Comment: hmmm changed the query to SELECT * FROM [nt:file] AS file INNER JOIN [nt:resource] AS resource ON ISSAMENODE(file,resource) WHERE CONTAINS(file.*,'external') OR CONTAINS(resource.*,'external') but still no result, is there some way to debug this query? Like some instrument for jcr repository management, something pgAdmin-like etc...

Comment: Finally got it working, seems the problem was I had named my property keys as namespace:key, which was interpreted as a node instead. Aftear I changed it, it worked, posted the solution query in the question. Thanks again!